# Angular 2 get json data from url

Tags: javascript, json, angular, calendar

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
let ep = './data.json';
this.events = this.http
  .get(ep, { headers: headers })
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map(({results}: { results: Data[] }) => {
    return results.map((data: Data) => {
      return {
        title: data.title,
        start: new Date(data.from),
        colors.yellow,
      };
    });
  });
```

Here is my code in Angular 2. I want to get data from a JSON file and show it in the angular-calendar. 
[Here is angular-calendar Demo](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/demos/#/kitchen-sink): How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a service that contains the data for the calendar.

```
getList(): any
{

var date = new Date( '2017-01-12' );
var date2 = new Date( '2017-03-17' );

return (
  [

    { title: 'Beauty And The Beast', start: date2, color: { primary: '#e3bc08', secondary: '#FDF1BA' } },

    { title: 'La La Land', start: date, color: { primary: '#e3bc08', secondary: '#FDF1BA' } }

  ]
)
}
```

Then you will have to remove the async pipe from the template.

Before:

```
[events]="(events | async ) || []
```

After:

```
[events]="(events) || []
```

Then call the service in the component:

```
fetchEvents()
{

this.events= this._data_Service.getList()

}
```

---

**2**. To get `data.json` file with `Http` you need to put the JSON file in the assets folder: `./assets/data.jsom`, so that it can be accessed by the application: `localhost:8080/data.json`.

Then you simply make a get request.

```
fetchEvents(): void {


    this.events = this.http
      .get('../../assets/data.json') // the path may vary depending 
                                    // on your directory structure. 
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map((results) => {  // this might be different depending on
                          //  your json and type definition.

        return results.map((data: Data) => {

          console.log({title: data.title,
            start: new Date(data.from),
            color: colors.yellow})

          return {
            title: data.title,
            start: new Date(data.from), 
            color: colors.yellow,data
          };
        });
      });


}// fetchEvents
```

Here is the JSON I used:

```
[

{"title":"La La Land","from":1490475722305},
{"title":"Beauty And The Beast","from":1490475722305}

]
```

finally, you can include the type definition in your component:

```
interface Data {

  title: string;
  from:string;

}

interface DataEvent extends CalendarEvent {
  data: Data;

}
```